# Eclipse Text Editor Behaviour under Linux

Tags: eclipse, editor

I use `Eclipse Luna 4.4.0` under `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`. When I edit a file (especially a Java file), then the editor has a vi-like behaviour with a command and edit mode. But I want the same editor behaviour as under Windows which is like `Notepad(++)`, without a command mode.

I couldn't find any key settings under `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys`. There's a default scheme, a `"vim's key bindings"` scheme and an `emacs` scheme, but there seems to be no difference between the default and the `vim` scheme. And, additionally, I couldn't find any way to export Windows' editor preferences and to import them under Linux.

Is there any way to solve my problem? Or do we have this different behaviour due to platform-dependent implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you have [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) or a different plug-in installed that provides these key bindings. If you don't want to have these features, try to uninstall them (select **Help** -> **About** from the menu, then click on **Installation Details** button on the bottom of the About dialog, where you can look for any possible culprits, and uninstall them.